# High CPU utilization when enabling jprofiler agent

Tags: java, jprofiler

I have noticed that my profiled server is getting high CPU (almost 100% CPU utilization!). is there something that I'm missing to make it lower?

Please advice on this issue since I need to use Jprofiler.

thanks!

Comment: Without recording anything, there should be nearly no overhead. With CPU recording alone in sampling mode, the overhead should not be higher than 10%.

Answer (score 0):

> is there something that I'm missing to make it lower?

In general, the increase in CPU is due to the (significant) overheads involved in capturing and recording profiler (JVMTI) events.

According to [the JProfiler Help](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/index.html), it is possible to turn off some types of profiler events.  Doing this should reduce the overheads, but the flip side is that (obviously) those events are not available for later analysis.

Specifically

- The "Help Topics > Profiling > Behind the scenes" section talks about events, and mentions that they can be turned off and on.
- The "Reference > Managing Sessions > Profiling Settings > *" subsections describe the various settings that cover this.  You would need to drill down to figure out how to turn off the events you are not interested in recording.

Comment: thanks! I am using a pretty weak server (amazon cloud c3.large) I see that no matter how I configure it I found that it is "eating" my CPU and the server is beyond functionality.

Comment: It is not just "beyond functionality".  It is impossible to profile an application without consuming extra resources in the process ... irrespective of how you implement the profiling.

Comment: OK, so if referring to your exprience what would you suggest I would configure it? since this server is pretty weak...